# PHP read JSON-POST-Request and send them back

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

I tried with PHP to read JSON-POST-Request, but I get the following error.

> Request failed: parsererror

Here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="resources/js/model/Product.js"></script>
<script>
    function getdetails(){

        var p = new Product(15,11.5,"Pizza Test","P");
        var z = new Product(68,1.5,"Zutate Test","Z");

        p.addOneProduct(z);

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yb_test_post.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(p)
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            $("#msg").html( " Post parameter are: <br/>"+msg );
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
</script>
```

and my PHP-Code, I try to read the POST request and immediately print

```
    <table>
<?php


    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }


?>
</table>
```

What do i wrong?

Product.js

```
function Product(id, price, name, type){
    this.id = id;
    this.price = +price;
    this.totalPrice = +price;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.products = [];
    var self = this;

    this.addOneProduct = function(oneProduct){
        self.products.push(oneProduct);
        self.totalPrice= self.totalPrice+oneProduct.price;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `data: JSON.stringify(p)`.  This is sending a JSON string as the post body.  You don't want this.  PHP will not automatically parse this for you.  You want to send PHP a query string, this will make PHP automagically parse it into the `$_POST` array.

Lose the `JSON.stringify`, and just try this: `data: p`.

Also, `dataType: "json"` is the `Content-type` of the ***response***, not the ***request***.  Your PHP is sending back HTML, so you want: `dataType: "html"`.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yb_test_post.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: p
});
```

Comment: I tried, but now I get the following error message in the web console

TypeError: oneProduct is undefined
self.totalPrice= self.totalPrice+oneProduct.price;

Comment: @user1167253: I was afraid of that.  When serializing, jQuery will call functions to get their value.  To fix this, add `if(!oneProduct){ return '';}` as the first line in `addOneProduct`.

Comment: Thx, it's work.
But the Send-Format is not a JSON.
How can i send to PHP JSON?

Comment: @user1167253: Why do you want to send it as JSON?  It's better to send it as a query string.  If you do it this way, `$_POST` will populated automagically.  If you want JSON, you'd have to parse it manually (I can show you how to do that if you *really* want).

Comment: I can send as a query string, it is not so important. The main thing for me is that I easily convert to Object the data that I get on the server.
Is there a solution for this in PHP?

Comment: @user1167253: Yes, it's called `$_POST`.  It is automatically filled with the query string values.  Your current PHP code should work.  Does it not?  The only problem is when the key is `products`, the value would be an array.